# python multiprocessing worker memory consumption increases indefinitely

Tags: python, multiprocessing, out-of-memory

I have a list of Excel 2010 files (xlsx) that need to be searched for a specific value. As xslx is a binary format this cannot be done with normal text editors. So I do the following for each file

1. get file name
2. open in pandas
3. convert dataframe to numpy array
4. check array for value

This calls for multiprocessing as it is not I/O-bound. The time is needed for the pandas stuff and the array conversion. So I have set up a multiprocessing version of my script (see below):

The problem is the memory consumption of each worker process. It builds up continuously peaking in 2GB per worker although each xlsx file is merely 100kb. I do not see why the memory is not released before a new file is processed. This way I run out of memory before my list of files is processed.

The problem seems to be not the queue, but the pandas stuff.

Here is my code. It can be tested with any xlsx files you have on your system.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
import glob

path = r'c:\temp'
fileFilter = 'serial.xlsx'
searchString = '804.486'


def searchFile(tasks, results, searchString):
    """Iterates over files in tasks and searches in file for the
    occurence of 'searchString'.

    Args:
    -----
    tasks: queue of strings
        Files to look in
    results: queue of strings
        Files where the searchString was found
    searchString: str
        the string to be searched
    """
    # for files in the queue
    for task in iter(tasks.get, 'STOP'):
        # read the filestructre into memory
        xfile = pd.ExcelFile(task)
        # iterate all sheets
        for sheet in xfile.sheet_names[:3]:
            # read the sheet
            data = pd.read_excel(xfile, sheet)
            # check if searchString is in numpy representation of dataframe
            if searchString in data.values.astype(str):
                # put filename in results queue
                results.put(task)
                break
        xfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get all files matching the filter that are in the root path
    print('gathering files')
    files = glob.glob(path + '\**\{}'.format(fileFilter), recursive=True)

    # setup of queues and variables
    n_proc = 2
    tasks = mp.Queue()
    results = mp.Queue()

    print('Start processing')
    # setup processes and start them
    procs = [mp.Process(target=searchFile,
                        args=(tasks, results, searchString))
             for x in range(n_proc)]
    for p in procs:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    # populate queue
    for file in files:
        tasks.put(file)

    for proc in procs:
        tasks.put('STOP')

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    # print results
    for result in range(results.qsize()):
        print(results.get())

    print('Done')
```

Comment: As a side note - `.xlsx` files are zip-compressed archives with xml inside. If the only thing you need is to search for a value you can unzip and search the stream without any extra modules.

Comment: It is not the only thing to do.... Can I unzip them with the python internal zip-module?

Comment: Tried to unzip the xlsx-files and it generates many xml-documents: for style, for each worksheet, themes,... finding the xml-document with the values is rather difficult.

Comment: Yep, it is a bit of a mess - but there is order to that chaos. If you are mostly searching for or extracting values - it might be easier (and less memory intensive) with SAX / DOM parser as compared to pandas. Otherwise - look at other libs that can make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem in gc, which can't gather pandas frames in function context which you never leave. You can use `multiprocessing.Pool.map` which can do queue handling for you. Worker function will be called for every item and let gc do the job. Also you can use `maxtasksperchild` Pool constructor param to limit amount of items handled by worker.

```
import glob
import multiprocessing


def searchFile(task, searchString):
    xfile = pd.ExcelFile(task)
    ...
    if found:
        return task


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = glob.glob(path + '\**\{}'.format(fileFilter), recursive=True)
    searchString = '804.486'

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2, maxtasksperchild=10)

    args = ((fname, searchString) for fname in files)
    matchedFiles = filter(None, pool.map(searchFile, args))
    pool.close()
```

Comment: Tried this... Did not solve the problem, since to problem is not the code, but one of the files. Checked with a different set of files and it works without a problem. Thanks anyway.